# cat() function returns unexpected stuff in R programming?

Tags: r

I tried the following codes:

> cat("spring")

and it returns

spring>

what happened to my R shell?

Comment: Try `cat("spring\n")`

Comment: Nothing happened. Just hit enter again.

Comment: To elaborate, see the following from `help("cat")`: *No linefeeds are output unless explicitly requested by "\n"*. In other words, `cat("spring")` prints `"spring"` to the console and does not move to a new line before printing the prompt character (`>`  in your case)

Comment: Oh, it works. Thank you!